# convert nested string element into list with one element in python

Tags: python, string, list, nested

Hope this is a simple one.

I have the following json:

```
{
   'listTitle': 'dsadasdsa',
   'chapters': 'testchapter',
   'sublist': [
      {
         'subListCreator': 'jan',
         'item': [
            {
               'itemTitle': 'dasdasd',
               'itemContext': 'None'
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Of which I can print my *testchapter* value by doing:

```
  print(data['chapters'])
```

Here's the question, I would like to do two things:

1. Remove the complete chapters element in case there is an empty chapter-string:  `'chapters': ''`
2. Convert chapters to a list containing the testchapter-value.

Desired outcome in case of scenario 1:

```
{
    'listTitle': 'dsadasdsa',
    'sublist': [
       {
          'subListCreator': 'jan',
          'item': [
             {
                'itemTitle': 'dasdasd',
                'itemContext': 'None'
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

Desired outcome in case of scenario 2:

```
{
    'listTitle': 'dsadasdsa',
    'chapters': [
       'testchapter'
    ],
    'sublist': [
       {
          'subListCreator': 'jan',
          'item': [
             {
                'itemTitle': 'dasdasd',
                'itemContext': 'None'
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

Tried a bunch of things but did not manage so far. Either it remained a string instead of list while looking like a list. Or all the string-characters were converted to individual list elements etc.

Hope you can help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutating the dict in place is the simplest way if that's an option:

```
if data['chapters']:
    data['chapters'] = [data['chapters']]
else:
    data.pop('chapters')
```

Building a new dict via a comprehension might look like:

```
{k: [v] if k == 'chapters' else v for k, v in data.items() if v or k != 'chapters'}
```

The key thing that it sounds like you weren't able to find was that to turn a single value `v` into a list containing that value, you want to use the list literal expression `[v]`.  If you do `list(v)`, you'll get a list containing each item from the iteration of `v` (so if `v` is a string, you get a list of its individual characters).

Comment: Thank you so much, this first solution directly works like a charm!